# What condition should I use to cut off unnecessary shapes? (not the center of the image!)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, conditional-statements

I need to find the ellipses in the image with OpenCV. But my program finds both necessary and unnecessary ones. Idea was to separate the unnecessary ones using the condition of hitting the point area:

```
x_ellipse<(w/2+magic_num) and x_ellipse>(w/2-magic_num) and y_ellipse<(h/2+magic_num) and y_ellipse>(h/2-magic_num)
```

But the problem is that real center `(w/2; h/2)` of image is not the center of necessary ellipses. Maybe there is another way to separate or OpenCV has some cool functions that can find center of that I need?
I am only interested in those ellipses that describe only the first 3 light ones

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

input_image = cv2.imread('test_image_2.bmp')

thresh = cv2.cvtColor(t2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray', thresh)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(thresh, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 101, 0)
cv2.imshow('circles', thresh)
#cv2.imwrite('thresh.bmp', thresh)

h, w, c = input_image.shape
#print('width:  ', w)
#print('height: ', h)
#print('channel:', c)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours( thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS)

for cnt in contours:
    if len(cnt)>5:
        ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
        #cv2.ellipse(t2,ellipse,(0,0,255),2)

        #param = ellipse[1][0]/ellipse[1][1]
        #if ellipse[0][0] < (w/2 + 25) and ellipse[0][0] > (w/2 - 25) and ellipse[0][0] < (h/2 + 25) and ellipse[0][0] > (h/2 - 25):
        cv2.ellipse(input_image,ellipse,(0,0,255),2)
        #else:
            #cv2.circle(t2, (int(ellipse[0][0]), int(ellipse[0][1])), 1, (255, 0, 0), -1)
        
        #draw center of image
        #cv2.circle(input_image, (int(w/2), int(h/2)), 10, (255, 255, 0), -1)
        
        #if param < 0.88:
            #cv2.ellipse(t2,ellipse,(0,0,255),2)
        #else:
            #cv2.ellipse(t2,ellipse,(0,255,0),2)
        #print(ellipse[0])
        
cv2.imshow('contours', input_image)
        
cv2.waitKey()
```

Input image:

[image: Input image]

Center of image:

[image: Center of image]

All ellipses:

[image: All ellipses]

Comment: [Input image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDgkc.png
[Center of image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yGjB.jpg
[All ellipses]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbEuN.jpg

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the pictures there. -- you want to find circles, not ellipses. just stretch the picture correctly, then all your ellipses become circles. -- this has to do with physics, right? some interference/fringe pattern? I'm sure if you can point out what we're seeing and what exactly happens there, another simpler approach could be devised

Comment: Yes, It's interference. But input pics are not square. But how can I make the image square if I don't know the stretch factor? To do this, I need to first find out the true dimensions of the circles. It's kind of a vicious circle, isn't it?)

Comment: does the stretch ever vary? if not, just hardcode it. -- if that's actually a parameter, hmmm ok, can you rely on a fixed *center* at least? then I would suggest sampling through the center, a pixel row and a pixel column, and find in those 1D signals the extrema.

Comment: well, all pics that I have (I only work with images, which gives the device) are always 704x576 px.

Comment: So, I don't pretend to be elegant, but this crutch is suitable for my task) I use this condition:  `temp1 > 0.88 and temp2 > 1000` where temp1 is height/weight and temp2 is the area of the ellipse

Comment: 0.88 is the average ratio of the heights and widths of necessary ellipses; 1000 - I chose experimentally. If there is another way to separate - it will be very useful for me :)

Comment: I suggest you to try cv2.moment.